How does higher bandwidth relate to higher data transfer rates in optical communication?
I am looking into the benefits of using optical communication over radio frequency communication and I understand that the Shannon–Hartley theorem tells the maximum rate at which information can be transmitted using a specified bandwidth by
$${\displaystyle C=B\log _{2}\left(1+{\frac {S}{N}}\right)}$$
But what is the physics behind this? Why does a higher bandwidth allow for more information transfer? Why does using a higher frequency EM wave lead to a higher bandwidth?


Why does a higher bandwidth allow for more information transfer?

At baseband, it should be clear that more bandwidth means your signal can change more times per second, and that each change in the signal can convey information.
For bands above baseband you can see that the behavior is the same due to the modulation property of the Fourier transform,
$$f(t)g(t) \iff X(\omega)\star G(\omega),$$
where $\star$ indicates convolution.
That is, the signal with modulation is just the baseband signal shifted up to a higher frequency band.
We can do more complicated modulation schemes than just multiplying our baseband signal by the carrier (AM), but the basic principle remains --- the modulated signal doesn't convey more information than a baseband signal with the same spectral shape.

Why does using a higher frequency EM wave lead to a higher bandwidth?

Because a real-valued signal has both negative and positive fourier transform components. Normally we don't think much about the negative frequencies, because we know that (again, for real-valued time-domain signals) $X(-f) = X^\ast(f)$, so we can perfectly reconstruct the negative components from the positive ones.
But it does mean that when you modulate an EM carrier wave with frequency $\omega_c$, you can at most use the bandwidth between 0 and $2\omega_c$, because otherwise your left sideband would start to overlap the right sideband of the negative frequency portion of your signal.

Let's say you're representing the information as a binary on-off keyed (OOK) sequence, and the bit rate is 1 bit/sec.  The minimum bandwidth that this bit rate and modulation format has is ~1 Hz.   Now, let's say we go to 10 bits/sec.  The mere fact that I have a higher time-domain frequency relates directly to a larger bandwidth, which in this case would be ~10 Hz.  It's a Fourier transform relationship.
Another way to think of this is to imagine a sine wave with a frequency the same as the bit rate.  As the frequency of the sine wave increases, the frequency increases.

When we are talking about bandwidth here, is it something different to the range of frequencies in the EM spectrum?

@OisínBloomer The range of frequencies in the EM spectrum is "Bandwidth."
